# How to turn off the Quick Fix popup in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running VS Code 1.52.1 in Windows, editing JavaScript code. I am a double-click, copy & paste junkie. I mouse over something, like a function name, with the intent to double click copy it to the clipboard. But sometimes VS Code wants to suggest a "Quick Fix". This would be OK with me, except that the Quick Fix is displayed in a popup that overlays the code I am attempting to copy. Depending on how fast I am working, I may not notice until I paste the "old" contents of the clipboard into my target location.

Take the following function, for example.

```
// function to allow a promise-oriented caller to invoke
// a callback-oriented function
function callbackToPromise( resolve, reject ) {
    return function done( err, data ) {
        if(err) {
            reject(err);
        }
        else {
            resolve(data);
        }
    }
}
```

I mouse over the function name and the Quick Fix appears, overlaying the line of code where the mouse is hovering. The fix itself is redacted to avoid irrelevant discussion.

[image]

This behavior is both inconvenient and annoying, as it shifts my focus from the code to the misbehaving tool. It's like stubbing my toe a dozen times a day.

How can I configure VS Code not to automatically display Quick Fix popups? I would much prefer if VS Code would simply underline the function name and let me press the hotkey to see the popup.

Comment: I feel like the "Quick Fix" has moved position. I don't think it was always positioned right under the mouse, it's a pretty annoying default.

Comment: @limitlessloop pretty annoying to say the least!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not aware of an exact/direct setting for the Quick Fix suggestion. What you can do though is to control the entire popup: increase the delay or disable it on mouse hover, then use shortcut keys to show it only when you want it to.

The settings for the mouse hover are `editor.hover.*`:

[image: settings for editor.hover]

```json
"editor.hover.delay": 300,
"editor.hover.enabled": true,
"editor.hover.sticky": true,
```

Set `editor.hover.delay` to some "high" value, so it gives you time to double-click to copy things before the popup appears. Or, disable it entirely with `editor.hover.enabled`.

As for the hotkeys, in Keyboard Shortcuts, there's `editor.action.showHover`:

[image: keyboard shortcut showHover]

You can disable the popup on mouse hover with `editor.hover.enabled` set to `false`, and then just use the shortcut key to show it manually (I'm using a Mac so it's showing Mac shortcut keys. There should also be one for Windows.)

From the popup, there's also a shortcut key for directly showing the Quick Fix suggestions. You can also configure that from Keyboard Shortcuts as `editor.action.quickFix`:

[image: keyboard shortcut quick fix]

Again, you can disable the popup on mouse hover with `editor.hover.enabled` set to `false` and then just use the Quick Fix shortcut key to show it as needed.

Comment: The hover delay is the perfect solution for me. Thanks for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 this is how I did it: Settings -> Text Editor -> Quick Suggestions Delay.

[image: Quick Fix Delay]