# How to enable the quick fix in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I disable the quick fix light bulb by mistake and I cant find any way to enable it back.
Thanks!

tried to find it on settings and to enable all extansions.

Comment: You might find a clue in [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65710221/)

Answer (score 1):

1. click ctrl + shift + P
2. type C/C++: Enable Error Squiggles

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).